# What is the Integration Account Callback URL for?

Tags: azure

The Azure Integration Account features a tab on its configuration blade labelled "Callback URL":

[image: Screenshot of the Integration Account configuration blade]

This is documented in terms of [generated API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/logic/integration-account-assemblies/list-content-callback-url) but this doesn't say anything about its purpose. I can't find any documentation that mentions it.

What is this URL for?

Answer (score 0):

*Basically the [**`callback uri`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/logic/integration-accounts/get-callback-url) we are using for reverifying/recheck the details of our integration account that we created earlier so that we can see properties of it. Likewise, we use [**`jwt.io`**](https://jwt.io/) to see the content of any token*.

***For example:-***
[image]
[image]

You can generate the `callback url` of an integration account using the below api with `post` method by passing the following parameter as mentioned in this [**`MS DOC`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/logic/integration-accounts/get-callback-url):-

```
POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Logic/integrationAccounts/{integrationAccountName}/listCallbackUrl?api-version=2016-06-01
```

Comment: Thanks. I have viewed this information, but I suppose I don't see what the purpose of doing so is, or what makes this a "callback". What is expected to call back to the integration account? I would call it a callback if the integration account initiates some process on an external endpoint which needs to _call back_ to report something. Generally Azure resources have a uniform REST API for querying this kind of information. Does the implementation of the callback uri pre-date the 'standard' resource manager API, and this is why there is a special implementation for just getting the config?

Comment: AFAIK, There is no specific documentation for this feature in integration account. But this feature can save customer time to get direct access.